# why can't I force quit blender?

Tags: modeling

Had a couple of situations recently where I blender has hung and I have to force quit.
Unfortunately, Blender still appears in the "Force Quit Applications" list even though the process is not running and not visible in ps -ax.

OSX Catalina.

This seems to be the only application on my system that does this. Everything else will respect the "Force Quit" action. Anyone know what I can do to kill this?

Even an attempt to shut down the computer cleanly fails because the O/S doesn't seem to be able to quit the (non-existent) process.

Is there a sub-process that I need to kill as well?

Comment: This sounds like an OSX bug.  Force Quit should shoot down the entire process tree descended from the force quit.  I would speculate a device driver is in a zombie mode because it can't finish unwinding Blender's use of the device, but that's a pretty wild speculation on so little information.

Comment: Would you be able to speculate on where OSX generates its list of processes from for use in "Force Quit"? I would hazard a guess it is a different place than the standard ps -ax output.

Comment: maybe ps -axM (to get info on every thread)